# How to use Verify command in Assertions.Can anyone give any Example

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng

How to use Verify command in Assertions.Can anyone give any Example.

Problem: While use assets,if one case is failed,it stopped to run.i need to use VERIFY (it will run,even if there any failures). Give me example for Verify command.

Comment: Did you try google "verify command example"? I got 59 million results.

Comment: Yes.i didn't get a perfect example

Comment: If you have means,please tell me @guy

Comment: I don't use it, so I can't help you with it.

Comment: But instead of looking for the perfect example as you put it, try to piece together working code from several sources.

Comment: Testng @Grasshopper

Comment: Any idea@Grassshopper

Comment: Just saw the testng tag... Check out the SoftAssert class in testng...

Comment: Yes got .thank you @Grasshopper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the TestNG [SoftAssert](http://testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/asserts/SoftAssert.html) class to perform multiple assertions without failing.

Example:

```
SoftAssert softAssert = new SoftAssert();
--Do test stuff--
softAssert.assertTrue(true, "Is this true?");
softAssert.assertFalse(true, "Is this true?");
softAssert.assertAll();
```